# How to disable re-negotiate in Spring boot embedded jetty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jetty, embedded-jetty

Generally we can disable Client-initiated re-negotation in Jetty containers by setting the below property jetty.xml

```
<New id="ssl" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
    <Set name="allowRenegotiate">FALSE</Set>
```

I would like to disable re-negotation in Spring boot embedded jetty. I checked below links but I didn't find any related property to implement this.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.4.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/Ssl.java

Could someone please provide me some pointers to implement this. Appreciate your help.

**Edited:**

From the below link, I can see that by default allowRenegotiate is set to false. Is it is the same case with embedded Jetty?

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/SSL_Connectors

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your question about embedded Jetty, `allowRenegtionate` is `true` [by default](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/util/ssl/SslContextFactory.html#isRenegotiationAllowed--); it is also on by default if you enable the `ssl` module in a current Jetty distribution.

I am unsure what version of Jetty you are using, but the wiki you linked to is for Jetty 7 and 8 which are both End of Life and no longer under active development. I strongly encourage you to upgrade to the [latest release](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html) of Jetty, if possible, and to refer to [current documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/) as much has changed.

Comment: Note `org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector` is from Jetty 7 or Jetty 8 (that class does not exist in Jetty 9+)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using jetty 9.3.16, from the documentation link you have provided, I can see the method named  setRenegotiationAllowed() can be used to disable renegotiation. Will try to implement it. As I told earlier spring boot didn't provide external property support to enable/disable renegotiation